# difference between these two ways of creating a 'private' property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate a simple Holder "class" in JavaScript with a "private" property that holds something and "public" getter and setter "methods" to access the value.

The approach exhibited by `HolderA` below is mentioned e.g. [here](https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript). The other approach I more or less arrived at by mutation but I guess it must be recognizable as an idiom as well. I like it because it contains no `this` or `prototype` stuff and seems very elementary and functional. Is there a difference between the two?

The test code (I run it under `nodejs`) seems to suggest that the two approaches are identical except that in the first case the objects I get have `typeof` `object` whereas in the second `function`.

```
var test = function(o) {
    var initialValueCorrect = (!(typeof o.getX()==='undefined'))&&(o.getX()===0);
    var VALUE_TO_SET = 10;
    o.setX(VALUE_TO_SET);
    var getSetWorks = o.getX()===VALUE_TO_SET;
    var xIsPrivate = (typeof o.x === 'undefined');
    var xHasCorrectValue;
    if (!xIsPrivate)
        xHasCorrectValue = o.x === VALUE_TO_SET;
    return {initialValueCorrect: initialValueCorrect,
            getSetWorks : getSetWorks,
            xIsPrivate: xIsPrivate,
            xHasCorrectValue: xHasCorrectValue};
};

var HolderA = (function() {
    function foo(x) {
        this.getX = function() {
            return x;
        };
        this.setX = function(_x) {
            x = _x;
        };
    };
    return foo;
})();

var createHolderB = (function() {
    var x;
    function foo(_x) {
        x = _x;
        return foo;
    }
    foo.getX = function() {
        return  x;
    };
    foo.setX = function(_x) {
        x = _x;
    };
    return foo;
})();



var objects = [{object: new HolderA(0), name: "approach with constructor-invocation and 'this'"},
               {object: createHolderB(0), name: "approach with normal function invocation and closed variable"}];


for (var i = 0; i<objects.length ; i++) {
    var testResult = test(objects[i].object);
    console.log('['+objects[i].name+']: the object is a: '+(typeof objects[i].object)
                +'\n\n\t\t\t'+JSON.stringify(testResult)+'\n\n\n\n\n');
}
```

## update

As `Bergi` has pointed out function `createHolderB` in my code above is plain wrong and only creates a singleton object. So, is not really a "constructor" function. To that end I've now created `createHolderC` which can be used to really create multiple objects with a hidden private property like this:

```
var objectC1 = createHolderC()(0);
```

Now, is there any material difference between `HolderA` and the `createHolderC` function or is the difference purely stylistic?

```
var createHolderC = function () {
    return (function() {
        var x;
        function foo(_x) {
            x = _x;
            return foo;
        };
        foo.getX = function() {
            return x;
        };
        foo.setX = function(_x) {
            x = _x;
        };
        return foo;
    })();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createHolderB` does not create new holders like `HolderA` does. It's essentially a singleton pattern. You might also want to call it a module. Notice that `createHolderB() === createHolderB`.

`createHolderC` is still different from `HolderA` in that it returns function objects, not instances. You may see the differences better when you strip out the unnecessary IEFEs:

```
function HolderA(x) {
    this.getX = function() {
        return x;
    };
    this.setX = function(_x) {
        x = _x;
    };
    // implicit `return this;` when called via `new`
}

function createHolderC() {
    var x;
    function foo(_x) {
        x = _x;
        return foo;
    };
    foo.getX = function() {
        return x;
    };
    foo.setX = function(_x) {
        x = _x;
    };
    return foo;
}
```

A typical factory would rather look like this:

```
function createHolderD(x) {
    var foo = {};
    foo.getX = function() {
        return x;
    };
    foo.setX = function(_x) {
        x = _x;
    };
    return foo;
}
```

(or even with `return {getX: …, setX: …};`), the only difference to `HolderA` is the prototypical inheritance then.

Comment: updated code with a correct functional "constructor" function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically both exhibits the `private` access behavior to the `x` variable. But the difference between those two are

1. Constructor function

   ```
   var HolderA = (function() {
     function foo(x) {
       this.getX = function() {
           return x;
       };
       this.setX = function(_x) {
           x = _x;
       };
     };
     return foo;
   })();
   ```

   This is a self executing function, where it returns **Constructor** foo.

   That is the reason you are using `new` while creating this type of holder `{object: new HolderA(0)`
2. A function

   ```
   var createHolderB = (function() {
     var x;
     function foo(_x) {
       x = _x;
       return foo;
     }
     foo.getX = function() {
       return  x;
     };
     foo.setX = function(_x) {
       x = _x;
     };
     return foo;
   })();
   ```

   Even this is also a self executing function, but while execution it creates x variable and returns function foo, and foo access `x` by **closure.**

    You are creating this type of holder just by normal function call `object: createHolderB(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are really bad in practice.

If you're making [**closures**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/607407) (anonymous functions) that hold your "*private variable*" scope, it means you're creating those functions for **every instance of the class**. That costs memory and performance. I used to create classes like this, but then once I was making large number of instances and found out that it hits performance hard.

Just as in Python, make private variables private by some convention, like underscore in `_name`. Then you can break it for debug reasons (because variables in closure scope are not accessible).

This is how I would do it:

```
function MyClass(arg) {
    this._privateVar = arg;
}
MyClass.prototype.getPrivateVar = function() {
  return this._privateVar;
}
```

You can also make getters and setters:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, "privateVar", {
    get: function() {
      return this._privateVar;
    }
}
```

But don't try to push javascript into things it's not designed to, or you'll pay with performance, code readability and debugging complexity. Applies to other languages too.